# Solve $\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} + \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = 2$

Tags: trigonometry

I am fairly good at solving trig equations yet this one equation has me stumped. I've been trying very hard but was unable to solve it. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} + \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = 2$$

solve for $x$ in the range of $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$

I do know we have to do a difference of squares, yet after that, I don't know what to do and I get lost.

Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ might be helpful.

Comment: For that matter: $u+\frac1{u}=2$ has only *one* solution. That can be very helpful here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} + \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}&=\frac{\cos^2 x+(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2x+1+2\sin x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\;;
\end{align*}$$

now use a familiar trig identity and find something to cancel.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I didn't try this!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  if you put the two fractions over a common denominator you get a nice cancellation.

Comment: I should have thought of that! +1

Answer (score 1):

You have a fraction and its reciprocal adding to $2$: $\lambda + 1/\lambda=2$. Only solution is $\lambda=1$, as @J.M. has noted. So $\cos x = 1+\sin x$. Draw the graphs of the two sides of the equation and see that there are five intersections in the $x$-interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]$, but the two at $x=-\pi/2$ and $x=3\pi/2$ are no good, ’cause there you get $0/0$ occurring in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin {align*}
&  2=\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} + \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}\\
& =\frac{\cos^2 x+(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\\
& =\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2x+1+2\sin x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\\
& =\frac{2+2 \sin x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)} \, \\
& =\frac{2( 1+\sin x) }{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\;\\
& =\frac{2}{\cos x}\;
\end{align*}$$
$$ \rightarrow \cos x = 1, x = 2 k \pi  $$

Comment: This does not seem to add much to the method of Brian M. Scott. Can you edit this to add more value?

Comment: cross multiplication simplification, old favorite method.

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos x\cdot\cos x=(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)$

$$\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\dfrac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}$$

So, the given relation reduces to $$\dfrac2{\cos x}=2\iff\cos x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

After simplification, with condition $1 + \sin x \ne 0$ (or $x \ne 3\pi/2$),  the given equation becomes:

$$\frac{\cos x}{(1 + \sin x)} + \frac{(1+ \sin x)}{\cos x} = \frac{2}{\cos x} = 2\;,$$

which implies that

$$\cos x = \frac22 = 1\;.$$

Calculators and the Trig Unit Circle give as answers:

$x = 0$ (or $0$ deg.) and  $x = 2\pi$ (or $360$ deg.)

Let's check: when $x = 0$ or $x = 2\pi$, we have $\cos x = 1$ and $\sin x = 0$, then:

$1/1 + 1/1 = 2$ (True).

Comment: would be nice if you showed all the steps, and used some latex.

Comment: Worth noting that $x=-2\pi$ also works.