# Trig Identity Proof $\frac{1 + \sin\theta}{\cos\theta} + \frac{\cos\theta}{1 - \sin\theta} = 2\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

I've been working on this for like half an hour now and don't seem to be getting anywhere. I've tried using the double angle identity to write the LHS with $\theta/2$ and have tried expanding the RHS as a sum. The main issue I'm having is working out how to get a $\pi$ on the LHS or removing it from the right to equate the two sides. 
$$\frac{1 + \sin\theta}{\cos\theta} + \frac{\cos\theta}{1 - \sin\theta} = 2\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Comment: The procedure you have suggested should work.  Please show what you have done and explain clearly where you are stuck.

Comment: To help show your work better, here's a starting point into the instructions for how to format math formulas on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Have you tried to show the two quotients on the left are equal, and used the addition theorem for tan on the right?

Comment: Yeah I got up to that part but don't know how to get rid of the pi/4

Comment: Did you use the fact that $\tan(\pi/4) = 1$?  Also, could you show us what you have done?

Comment: What? How did you get that

Comment: Ohhh nvm. Thanks

Comment: Could be useful to know that $\tan(\theta/2)=\frac {\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$

Comment: Lol I'm an idiot. How did i not realise that tan45 was 1 xd. The question is easy now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**:
\begin{align}
& \cos\theta = \cos^2(\theta /2) - \sin^2(\theta/2)= (\cos (\theta/2) +\sin (\theta/2))(\cos (\theta/2) - \sin (\theta/2)), \\[10pt]
& 1 \pm\sin \theta = (\cos (\theta/2) \pm \sin(\theta/2))^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, I understand the first formula. How did you get the second one (after the comma)?

Comment: To  juA :.....$(\cos A/2 \pm \sin A/2)^2=$ $(\cos^2 A/2+\sin^2 A/2)\pm 2\cos A/2 \sin A/2=$ $1\pm 2\cos A/2 \sin A/2=$ $1\pm \sin A.$

Comment: Here's the derivation of the part after the comma in some detail: $$ \begin{align} & \left( \cos\left( \frac\theta2 \right) \pm \sin\left( \frac\theta2\right) \right)^2 \\ \\ = {} & \cos^2 \left(\frac\theta2\right) \pm 2\cos\left( \frac\theta2\right)\sin \left( \frac\theta2\right) + \sin^2 \left( \frac\theta2 \right) \\ \\ = {} & 1 \pm 2 \cos \left( \frac\theta2 \right) \sin \left( \frac\theta2\right) \quad \text{since } \sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha = 1\\ \\ = {} & 1 \pm \sin\theta \qquad \text{by the double-angle formula for the sine function.} \end{align} $$ $${}$$

Comment: Nice. I actually did exactly that in my proof, I just didn't treat it as an identity and go straight to it

Answer (score 2):

Let $\dfrac\theta2+\dfrac\pi4=y\implies\theta=2y-\dfrac\pi2$

$$\sin\theta=\cdots=-\cos2y,\cos\theta=\cdots=\sin2y$$

$$\dfrac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{1-\cos2y}{\sin2y}=\dfrac{2\sin^2y}{2\sin y\cos y}=?$$

$$\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}=\dfrac{\sin2y}{1+\cos2y}=?$$

See also : [Solve $\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} + \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139508/solve-frac-cos-x1-sin-x-frac1-sin-x-cos-x-2/2332514#2332514),

Comment: An elegant, not to mention efficient, approach.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\theta=\pi/2-x$, so the left-hand side becomes
$$
\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}
$$
Now recall that
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=
\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}
$$
so the left-hand side is actually
$$
2\cot\frac{x}{2}=2\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)=
2\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)
$$

Answer (score 0):

LHS:
$$\frac{(1 + \sin\theta)(1-\sin\theta)}{\cos\theta(1-\sin\theta)} + \frac{\cos\theta}{1 - \sin\theta} = \frac{2\cos\theta}{1 - \sin\theta}.$$

RHS:
$$2\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)=2\frac{\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}+1}{1-\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}}=2\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}=$$
$$2\frac{\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{2\cos\theta}{1 - \sin\theta}.$$